# How to convert PCM raw data to mp3 file?

Tags: java, android, mp3, converters

EDITED my question: Is there any encoders from PCM raw data to any audio file? mp3,ogg... but not WAV, as it will be too big

I do have a text file which has raw PCM array, and I want to convert it to mp3,ogg file. After long search I couldnt find some library which does provide this encoding (PCM to MP3). Im looking forward to have some suggestions or maybe links to such libraries.

It should be done programmatically in android phone, so I dont want to have some desktop solutions.

Comment: there is a question answered that should meet your requirements: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641920/how-to-encode-a-wav-to-a-mp3-on-a-android-device/

Comment: @MalaKa, I read that answer, I was expecting that something has been changed since 2010.. and that seems a little bit complicated for my level of knowledge..

Answer (score 0):

I think, you must check the licensing issues first. AFAIK mp3 software has never been free. Linux did support mp3, but had to build the code on the local machine instead of downloading a ready-to-use package. (Not sure if this has changed in recent years.)

[Re: EDITED] Other formats are easier, e.g.:

[How to encode Recorded voice to ogg vorbis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314816/how-to-encode-recorded-voice-to-ogg-vorbis)

[How to convert the WAV/OGG file to FLAC file in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733064/how-to-convert-the-wav-ogg-file-to-flac-file-in-android)

Comment: so you suppose if I will convert some music to MP3, i will have a problem with law?

Comment: So probably it is easier to have a Linux host converting mp3 to ogg for your application users...

Answer (score 0):

there is a github project that provides lame encoder for android
https://github.com/intervigilium/liblame

there is also an sample app that uses the library
https://github.com/intervigilium/Lame4Android

but as allready stated, if you want to encode/decode a mp3 file you may have to pay license/patent fees.

here you can find the mp3 license prices

http://mp3licensing.com/royalty