# Recording voice in OGG or MP3 formats in android phone

Tags: android, html

I have to record voice in `OGG/MP3` format using `Android MediaRecorder`. I need these formats to play with `HTML5` audio tag. The android documentation specifies in `MediaRecorder.OutputFormat` class about the formats but do not speak anything about which output format equals mp3 and ogg.

Whereas documentation also says that android supports mp3 and ogg vorbis on Supported Media Formats page. Very much confused, please clarify.

Answer (score 4):

None of the formats equals *mp3* or *ogg*.

Android supports **decoding** *Vorbis* and *MP3* audio according to the [media formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) documentation - not **encoding**.

With the built-in tools the closest you can probably get is one of the `AAC_*` codecs inside of an `MPEG_4` file. AAC is designed as a successor to the MP3 file format.

But for an `.ogg` file you need to encode the audio with *Vorbis* encoder (to get the audio frames) and then package it inside an *Ogg* container.

If you really require *Vorbis* or *MP3*, there are few questions touching the subject already:

- [How to encode Recorded voice to ogg vorbis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314816/how-to-encode-recorded-voice-to-ogg-vorbis)
- [How to encode a WAV to a mp3 on a Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641920/how-to-encode-a-wav-to-a-mp3-on-a-android-device)

For most purposes I'd imagine having AudioEncoder set to one of the `AAC_*` formats and OutputFormat set to `MPEG_4` should provide you with a file that could be played back in most modern (audio) applications.

Comment: Thanks @Mikko Rantanen. Your suggestions are helpful. I also went through media jargon like media container, codecs and now I understand it better. I created a recording with **Media File** set to `MPEG_4` and **Audio Codec** set to `AAC` and saved the file with `.mp3` extension. Its working in `HTML5 <Audio>` tag with `MIME` set to `audio/mpeg`. Now I doubt if it will become `MP3` which is patented and licensed format? I want a royalty free media type and `AAC` is available in Android API 10 onward. Is there any open source library which can be used to convert `3GP` audio to convert `OGG`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your direction worked and I am using `AAC` encoder with `MPEG_4` output format in Android. BTW I didn't find any conversion library in Android and stick to the above solution.

Comment: I think Android now supports encoding Vorbis no? With `MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.VORBIS`?

Comment: Thanks you solution worked after searching for hours for a solution!!!!